Why won't it allow me to unlock the last two words of the Bend Will shout?
Why won't Skyrim allow me to unlock the last two words of the Bend Will shout?
I have gone to all the word walls, absorbed all the words, and even revisited them. I have 14 dragon souls, and I still am unable to unlock the last two words.
